# Best way to handle interfaces in HTTP response

Tags: json, rest, go

I'm using an API that formats its responses in this way:

```
{
  "err": 0,
  "data": **Other json structure**
}
```

The way I'm getting a response right now is I'm putting the response in an struct like this:

```
type Response struct {
   Err int        `json:"err"`
   Data interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

and then I'm doing this after getting a response

```
jsonbytes, _ := json.Marshal(resp.Data)
json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &dataStruct)
```

I'm only ignoring errors for this example.
It seems kinda weird to me that I'm marshaling and unmarshaling when I know what the data is supposed to look like and what type it's supposed to be.

Is there a more simple solution that I'm not seeing or is this a normal thing to do?

Edit: I should probably mention that the Data attribute in the response object can vary depending on what API call I'm doing.

Comment: It does seem weird that you're marshaling and unmarshaling the data, I don't understand why you're doing that. You say you know how the data is supposed to be structured, so why do you need an `interface{}`? If you don't know what the structure is before hand, just extract the values from the generic types.

Comment: I know what the structure is before hand. I'm trying to abstract the response struct so I don't need to create a response struct for every API call.

Comment: @SamReynolds *Initialize* the Data field to the type you know is contained in the response json: https://play.golang.org/p/f2kTobiDoQY

Comment: @SamReynolds Take look at my `jsonapi` library and see how I write generic response JSON. My structure looks exactly like yours does, with a `Data` field and an `interface{}` type. https://github.com/lansana/jsonapi

Comment: Defining one struct type per endpoint (or per model) is perfectly "normal".

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you! That works perfectly. I didn't think of initializing Data to be a pointer to the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON unmarshaller uses reflection to look at the type it is unmarshalling to. Given an uninitialised `interface{}` as the destination for the unmarshalled data, a JSON `object` gets unmarshalled into a `map[string]interface{}` ([example in playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IK9WVjOFL5G)).

Here are some ideas.

## Option A

If you know the datatype, you can define a new response struct for each type. Example:

```
type FooResponse struct {
  Err  int `json:"err"`
  Data Foo `json:"data"`
}

type Foo struct {
  FooField string `json:"foofield"`
}

type BarResponse struct {
  Err  int `json:"err"`
  Data Bar `json:"data"`
}

type Bar struct {
  BarField string `json:"barfield"`
}
```

## Option B

If you prefer to have a single `Response` struct instead of one per type, you can tell the JSON unmarshaller to avoid unmarshalling the `data` field until a later time by using the `json.RawMessage` data type:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "log"
)

type Response struct {
  Err  int             `json:"err"`
  Data json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
}

type Foo struct {
  FooField string `json:"foofield"`
}

type Bar struct {
  BarField string `json:"barfield"`
}

func main() {
  fooRespJSON := []byte(`{"data":{"foofield":"foo value"}}`)
  barRespJSON := []byte(`{"data":{"barfield":"bar value"}}`)

  var (
    resp Response
    foo  Foo
    bar  Bar
  )

  // Foo
  if err := json.Unmarshal(fooRespJSON, &resp); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  if err := json.Unmarshal(resp.Data, &foo); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  fmt.Println("foo:", foo)

  // Bar
  if err := json.Unmarshal(barRespJSON, &resp); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  if err := json.Unmarshal(resp.Data, &bar); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  fmt.Println("bar:", bar)
}
```

Output:

```
foo: {foo value}
bar: {bar value}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Y7D4uhaC4a8

## Option C

A third option, as pointed out by @mkopriva in a comment on the question, is to use `interface{}` as an intermediary datatype and pre-initialise this to a known datatype.

Emphasis lies on the word intermediary -- of course passing around an `interface{}` is best avoided ([Rob Pike's Go Proverbs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=7m36s)). The use-case here is to allow any datatype to be used without the need for multiple different `Response` types. On way to avoid exposing the `interface{}` is to wrap the response completely, exposing only the data and the error:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "log"
)

type Foo struct {
  FooField string `json:"foofield"`
}

type Bar struct {
  BarField string `json:"barfield"`
}

type Error struct {
  Code int
}

func (e *Error) Error() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("error code %d", e.Code)
}

func unmarshalResponse(data []byte, v interface{}) error {
  resp := struct {
    Err  int         `json:"err"`
    Data interface{} `json:"data"`
  }{Data: v}

  if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &resp); err != nil {
    return err
  }

  if resp.Err != 0 {
    return &Error{Code: resp.Err}
  }

  return nil
}

func main() {
  fooRespJSON := []byte(`{"data":{"foofield":"foo value"}}`)
  barRespJSON := []byte(`{"data":{"barfield":"bar value"}}`)
  errRespJSON := []byte(`{"err": 123}`)

  // Foo
  var foo Foo
  if err := unmarshalResponse(fooRespJSON, &foo); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  fmt.Println("foo:", foo)

  // Bar
  var bar Bar
  if err := unmarshalResponse(barRespJSON, &bar); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  fmt.Println("bar:", bar)

  // Error response
  var v interface{}
  if err := unmarshalResponse(errRespJSON, &v); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
foo: {foo value}
bar: {bar value}
2009/11/10 23:00:00 error code 123
```

https://play.golang.org/p/5SVfQGwS-Wy

Comment: This is useful information, thank you. @mkpriva also pointed out that you can initialize the data attribute of the response struct to a pointer of the struct you expect, and then what ever struct that pointer is pointing to will be populated with the data. This is his example: play.golang.org/p/f2kTobiDoQY

Comment: That is a good point, certainly possible. I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @jsageryd please note that the idea with the pre-initialization rests on the assumption that you initialize the known type into a variable first, *then* you assign it to the Data field, and after unmarshal is done you use the variable not the Data field. So there is no need to do any additional type assertion as you point out in your answer. Basically *if the caller knows the type, then it can create and use a reference to the value of that type.* To see what i mean go here: https://play.golang.org/p/KAEE8dCDdFC

Comment: Ah! My bad. I did not understand that this is what you meant. Indeed a much better solution. I will revise the example to reflect your intention.